# Spring retry - Thread interruption handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, threadpool, spring-retry

I am using spring-retry v1.3.1 with @Retryable annotation and I have a few questions on its behaviour. Let's say that in my spring boot application I have a retry configuration that makes my application wait 1 hour before retrying.
If my application is killed (for example by kubernetes) while it was waiting in order to do a retry is there a way to catch it and do some operations before shutting down (logging for example)?
Also I'm not sure how spring-retry is using threads, if I end up with many retry attempts is there a risk that it blocks the application because of too many threads? Is there a way to give a dedicate thread pool to retryable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When interrupted, a `BackOffInterruptedException` is thrown to the caller so you can catch that.

`spring-retry` itself does not manage threads; that's up to you.

It is completely thread-based so, yes, you can end up with many suspended threads unless you manage the work with, for example, a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.